# Homological stability of Chow varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, morse-theory

Given a connected component $C$ of the degree $d$ Chow variety of $r$ cycles on $C_{d,r}(X)$ ($X$ is smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$), let $C'$ be another connected component of $C_{d',r}(X)$ for an arbitrary $d'$. Let's denote the closed immersion induced by the monoidal structure from $C$ to the connected component containing the $C+C'$ by $i$. Here $+$ is the monoidal operation on the Chow variety. Does $i$ induce an isomorphism on the $n$-th homology if $d$ is sufficiently larger than $n$?

This is true when $X=\mathbb{P}^n$ it is proved [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.4420.pdf). It relies heavily on the Lawson's suspension so is specialized to $X=\mathbb{P}^n$. I was trying to figure out a possibly a different way of proving it that can be generalized. (If the statement in the first paragraph seems true.)

This type of isomorphisms reminds me of Lefschetz type theorems which can only work when the closed subvariety is a complete intersection. So my second question is the following:

- Is $C$ a complete intersection in the closed embedding $i$? or zero locus of a global section of an ample vector bundle? (anything that satisfies some sort of property so Lefschetz type stability holds)

Comment: My answer to your previous question listed an example of a smooth, projective surface $X$ with trivial $\text{Pic}^0$ such that for infinitely many choices of degree $d'$ there is a component of $C_{d',1}(X)$ that is a singleton parameterizing a rigid effective divisor.  So if $C$ is a connected component that parameterizes ample divisors in $X$, then after adding enough copies of these divisors to the rigid divisor, the linear system is nonisolated.  Thus, $i$ does not induce an isomorphism in degree $n=2$ for infinitely many choices of $d'$.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thanks for the example. In your example the problem seems to be that there is a zero dimensional component in all degrees of the Chow variety, which still does not reject the statement that a Lefschetz type isomorphism could hold (because $n$ needs to the be less than the dimension of the closed subvariety). Do you think this still fails if I add an extra condition to make sure that $n$ is less that the dimension of $C$?

Comment: You can modify those examples to address the issue in your comment.  For the smooth projective surface $S$ above, and a curve $C\cong \mathbb{P}^1$, now let $X$ be the threefold $S\times C$.  Let $r$ be $1$.  Consider those curves in $X$ of degree $e$ that project isomorphically to their image in $S$, and such that the image is one of the "isolated" divisors $D\cong \mathbb{P}^1$ of $S$ of degree $d'$.  The parameter space of such curves is itself a projective linear space parameterizing curves in $C\times D \cong \mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$ . . .

Comment: . . . The dimension of that projective linear space might be arbitrarily large, depending on the degree of the curve in $S\times C$.  When we "glue" curves to these curves whose images in $S$ are sufficiently "free", the parameter space of deformed curves is now a scheme that has a morphism to a positive-dimensional linear space of moving divisors in $S$, where the fibers are again projective linear spaces.  In particular, this parameter space has Picard rank at least $2$, even though the original projective linear space has Picard rank $1$.

Comment: Just to add one more comment: you could ask your questions just in the special case that $r=1$ and the corresponding curves are isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$, the "simplest" curve (certainly the curve of smallest genus).  The issue I raise is that there are "non-free" curves -- curves that are somehow obstructed from moving freely.  You could exclude those.  Then when you ask your questions, you are very close to the conjectures of Cohen-Jones-Segal and of Batyrev-Manin (at least in the geometric case).  Those conjectures are wide open, although there are many partial results.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thanks, I wasn't aware of these conjectures.